# Can't install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a 2011 Hp Pavilion DV-6 laptop - stuck at "Welcome to Grub" screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, bios

similar questions have been asked before, but I could not find relevant information for my specific problem.
I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on this very laptop before, so I know it works.
What is different now is that I decided to partition the SSD and install Windows 10 Pro first. I thought that was a better idea rather than going Ubuntu first and then Win 10 to dual boot, as I know that Grub should be "fixed" in that case.
I used the latest version of Rufus to create a bootable USB pen drive and have downloaded the official Ubuntu release from Ubuntu website.
My laptop (HP Pavilion DV6 6157sl) has BIOS, not UEFI. I tried all the available options in Rufus, but the problem is still the same. In BIOS I have deselected the switchable graphic interfaces and opted for "fixed", I have also disabled the "virtualization" or something like that, as I remember that was an option that could have caused some compatibility issues with Linux.

Anyway, this is what happens:

A few minutes after rebooting, PC gets stuck on either:

```
Loading...
Welcome to GRUB!
```

{if the flash drive is written in ISO Image mode}

or

`GRUB`
{if the flash drive is written in DD Image mode}

The purple Grub splash screen does not even appear, just to be clear.
I have the latest available version of the BIOS for my machine.
I have used 2 different USB sticks in all 4 available (2.0) USB ports.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My 2006 Laptop would not install Ubuntu 20.04 that had run Ubuntu thru 2016 when retired, As test I installed 20.04 server and actually installed 20.04 Kubuntu which I use on my newer systems. Most older BIOS only systems need a lighter weight flavor. Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: Thank you @oldfred but as I said in my message I have been using Ubuntu on this very laptop for years. I know it works. I may have installed it on a different system and then swapped the ssd to the laptop, though. Can't remember that bit